# textAngular not replacing &nbsp

Tags: regex, angularjs

I'm using textAngular on a div with a character counter. Currently, a space (`&nbsp;`) is being counted as 6 characters. I can't figure out why my regex is not converting this to 1 character. I have tried many variation of a space in my regex, but have yet to get it (`&nbsp;`, \u00a0, (160)).
I want each space to be counted as one character. If there are multiple spaces in a row, each space should be one character.
I can easily solve this issue without textAngular, but sadly must keep textAngular in the project. I'm hoping someone has seen this before and is more familiar with textAngular.
Thank you in advance!

HTML:

```
<div name="htmlVariable" text-angular ta-toolbar="[[],['bold','italics','insertLink']]"
ng-model="modalOptions.htmlVariable"></div>

<strong><span class="questionNameCountdown">{{ 240-(modalOptions.htmlVariable |
htmlToPlaintext).length }} Remaining...</span></strong></p>
```

Angular Filter:

```
    app.filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
return function(text) {
    return String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
    }
});
```

`ng-model=modalOptions.htmlVariable` is just initializing `htmlVariable` to `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching regex for a week, it turns out I did not include: textAngular-sanitize.min.js

This file takes care of the issue.

At least I learned a good deal about regex!

Answer (score 0):

If you're typing `&nbsp` rather than `&nbsp;`, there's your problem. HTML entities don't work without that trailing semicolon.

Comment: Yes, I am using '&nbsp;'